# Archive page with multiple taxonomies rewrite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, archives, rewrite-rules

Ok, I've read over pretty much every answer to this question, but my situation must be unique somehow.

What I'm attempting to do is straightforward in theory.

- CPT: resource
- Tax1: resource_type
- Tax2: industry

When I register the CPT I have set the following:

```
'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'resources/%resource_type%',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
```

`'with_front' => false` because the standard posts is using a base.

I also have a page of `example.com/resources` with a template of `page-resources.php`.

When I register Tax1 I have set the following:

```
'rewrite'  => array( 
        'slug' => 'resources',
        'with_front' => false
    )
```

I have a `resource_type` term named `white-papers`.

This produces my first desired outcome of a permalink that looks like
`example.com/resources/white-papers/` for a taxonomy archive page using `taxonomy-resource_type.php`.

This is where things getting tricky. What I'm attempting to do is add a second taxonomy (Tax2) and create another archive page with a permalink of:

`example.com/resources/white-papers/enterprise`

This archive is a filtered archive of sorts in that it should show just the post that are of `resource_type = white-papers` AND `industry = enterprise`.

Instead I get `404`.

But if I try to a URL with a query of `example.com/index.php?post_type=resource&resource_type=white-papers&industry=enterprise` I get my desired filtered archive page.

Also, and I'm not sure if its relevant to the issue or not, but I have this function running:

```
function resources_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
  $rules = array();
  $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'resource_type',
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ) );

$post_type = 'resource';
foreach ($terms as $term) {    

    $rules['resources/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&resource_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

}
// merge with global rules
$wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'resources_cpt_generating_rule');
```

What I need help with is the rewrite rules for accomplishing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, so I thought I'd come back and answer my own question in case its useful to someone else.

To start, the CPT:

```
'query_var' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'resources',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
```

Tax1:

```
'query_vars' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 
        'slug' => 'resources/type',
        'with_front' => false
    )
```

Tax2:

```
'query_vars' => true,
'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false
    )
```

The rewrites:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^resources/type/([^/]*)/industry/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=resources&resource_type=$matches[1]&industry=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

This produces a slightly different URL structure than I originally intended, and while its a bit more verbose, I think it works just as well.

`example.com/resources` = `page-resources.php`

`example.com/resources/type/white-papers` = `taxonomy-resource_type.php` for Tax1 term `white-papers`.

`example.com/resources/type/white-papers/industry/enterprise` = the same `taxonomy-resource_type.php` archive template, but serves up only the CPT results of Tax1 AND Tax2.

This is exactly the functionality I was hoping to acheive.

Comment: This is really great answer!! thank so much for sharing @jedifunk